# What is the proper way to deal duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I'm in a bit of confusion about how the posts are flagged as duplicate . I know anyone can flag one's post irrespective of their reputation.

Edit: Ok, Anyone who have 50 rep can flag posts as duplicate. Sorry for that!!!

What if I asked a  question which is asked before and it has a solution which I tried is not working, and in my post I mentioned the code I used and the methods I followed. I might include error logs if occurred,but in my case I tried one method and it is not working for me.

Is my post still marked as duplicate?

I feel that if one's post is marked as duplicate then there would be more probability of that post getting down-voted .

Comment: `I know anyone can flag one's post irrespective of their reputation.` It actually requires 50 rep to flag as a duplicate.

Comment: _"I know anyone can flag one's post irrespective of their reputation."_ Actually, to flag for duplicate, one has to have 50 rep. Otherwise, you need 15.

Answer (score 5):

> What if I asked a question which is asked before and it has a solution which I tried is not working, and in my post I mentioned the code I used and the methods I followed. I might include error logs if occurred,but in my case I tried one method and it is not working for me.

Then *explain all of that in the question*.  Link to the other solution, show what you've done (if there's any relevant changes or context) and describe what happened, any errors, or how the result differed from what you want.  If you've done all of this then *the questions cease to be duplicates*.  The question makes it very clear that the other solution doesn't work, and since the answer doesn't answer the question, the questions aren't duplicates.

Comment: Can you please look this question i asked:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31077338/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-progress-bar-in-android-i-tried-one-way-and-it

Comment: @T_77 What about it do you want to know?

Comment: It is marked as duplicate. But , I mentioned everything as you said. What is your opinion about that post? Is that post deserved to be marked as duplicate?

Comment: No, that post is *not* marked as a duplicate.  There isn't even a single vote to close it as a duplicate.  One person flagged a post as a possible duplicate.  If others agree and vote to close then it might end up being closed as a duplicate.  If you feel that the question isn't already clear on why the proposed duplicate doesn't solve your problem, then you can edit the question to explain why the solutions posted there aren't working for you, or how they don't solve your problem.

Comment: Ohh, I feel that if one flagged it as duplicate, it will be likely marked as duplicate. Thank you for the information.

Comment: @T_77 the header that you see pointing to the other question is only visible to you.  It won't be visible to everyone else until the questions is actually closed as a duplicate.

Comment: that's good then. Thanks @psubsee2003