# What should I do when I find duplicates, but have <50 reputation points?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions, reputation

I was just looking for the answer to a random error I was getting from a program, and the first question I found was marked (correctly) as a duplicate of a much older post with a great, still relevant, answer. I noticed on the "Related" panel that there were a large number of questions all asking the exact same question, many of them with a decent amount of upvotes, that were not flagged as duplicates.

I would like to flag them all as duplicates, because they crowd out the answer that everybody is looking for, but I have less than 50 reputation points, so I don't have the right to flag as duplicate yet.

Am I allowed to use the "Needs Moderator Attention" flag and explain that it's a duplicate, or is that abusing the purpose of that flag? I'm not sure if I'm supposed to wait until having 50 reputation points to even address that issue, or if I can go through the "NMA" flag making the 50-reputation-points threshold simply a layer of verification that my flag isn't itself spam.

The only relevant part I see on the "[Flag Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)" policy page is:

> **What happens when I flag something as needs ♦ moderator attention?**
>
> You'll be required to enter a comment clearly explaining what the problem is. After that, these moderator flags go in a special high priority queue visible to all moderators. (Users with the Moderator Tools privilege cannot view these flags.) We take moderator flags quite seriously; rest assured that they are all followed up on!

I feel like this could be taken either way. Thoughts?

(I searched for a *very* long time to find another question like this so we don't have an inception incident on our hands, so my fingers are crossed this isn't a duplicate.)

Comment: Good on you for asking.  I see lots of users doing something wrong in cases like this, such as adding an answer with a link to the duplucate.   In general, there are tons of duplicates on SO, and it's not super important to have them all marked as duplicates, especially if both questions have good answers.  In general, if you don't have enough rep to perform an action, just do nothing.  Wait until you have the required rep, and then flag away when appropriate.

Comment: Related if not a duplicate: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297858/578411

Comment: Wait...you read the help page relevant to your question, searched thoroughly on meta before posting, and wrote a quality question about site policy...and you don't even have enough rep to flag yet?! Somebody, please give this man some reputation!

Comment: Too bad you don't get rep from meta questions ...

Comment: If you found your preferred answer this easily then nothing really went wrong that requires fixing.  Blindly close-voting Q+A just because they show up under the Related list is not a grand idea.

Comment: did you consider [making 25 edit suggestions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164042/165773)? If these are [well received](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/suggested-edits/info), you would get 50 rep and unlock commenting privileges

Comment: Hmm. It seems you now have 50 rep. So you can now comment and point out a possible duplicate or flag as a duplicate.

Comment: Well, I'd suggest go to a chat room which is talking about that programming language, post the question's link and the dupe link there since we just need 20 rep to *talk in chat* (what? someone even doesn't have 20 rep? Hmm...don't ask me about that). Or you can just come [**SOCVR**](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), it's a good place if you think a question should be closed or you need talk about something like that.

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate): *[Give an incentive for finding duplicate questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37466)*

Comment: @Glorfindel oh, but you *do* get rep from Meta questions, at least if the [massive surge of upvotes](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4722433/sean-branchaw?tab=reputation) this asker got upon posting this question is anything to go by. ;)

Comment: 50 rep? The help center says you can flag dupes at 15 rep. They should clarify the help center if it's actually 50.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't frequent the chat here (or much of anywhere), but I understand that can be a fairly reasonable option for those with 20+ rep, and the [Close Vote Reviewers room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) is probably the best place in chat for this.

If you have 15 rep but not 20 rep, you should probably submit two or three good edit suggestions, or otherwise get to 20 rep. A ♦ flag explaining that you don't have enough rep to flag it yourself just yet, along with the reason the questions are duplicates *might* work, but the mods tend to be leery about closing questions just on one user's say-so, however plausibly worded their flag, and this is especially true for duplicates, which require more specialized technical knowledge that mods don't, in general, necessarily have. (They all have plenty of technical knowledge, certainly, but asking [a mod with 300+k mostly in the web stack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) to mark a Haskell question as a duplicate is probably not the greatest idea.)

If you don't have 15 rep, or if the above options do not appeal to you, there's a nuclear option available to you. Write an **actual** answer summarizing and drawing from the other question's good answer(s), while customizing and extending it for this question, then post that. Hopefully you'll hit two birds with one stone, raking in enough rep not to have to repeat this in the future while giving the question a suitable answer. However, this does *not* mean just giving a link to the answer, as so many do, or even really giving a link and quoting the entire answer (which is … pretty much the bare minimum to not have your answer deleted). I don't expect these transgressions from someone careful enough to post such a good Meta question, but others reading this I'm not so sure about.

Of course, all this is obviated by the simple expedient you've already taken of getting enough rep to flag the usual way. Well done.